# How do I increase the fps in output

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, video, face-detection

I am trying to do face detection on a video file. I am using openCV HAAR Face Detector. I also resize the image by a suitable factor to enable faster processing. I have also used multiple threading but the threads are sequential. The output video lags a lot.
I want the output to be as fast as the input frames. Any suggestions as to how I can increase the frame rate in the o/p video.
Also can the threads be used in parallel? If yes, how?

The Face detection module in written in the file faceDetector.py

The sample gives 25 fps.

The program works fine with webCam.

My code:

```
import cv2

from threading import Thread

from faceDetector import Face

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("sample2.mp4")

class T1(Thread):

    def  __init__(self, frame):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.frame = frame
        self.imgResized = None

    def run(self):
        self.imgResized, self.faces = FaceDetection(self.frame)



class  T2(Thread):

    def __init__(self, img, faces):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.img = img
        self.faces = faces

    def run(self):
        Faceobj.RectAroundFace(self.faces, self.img)
        # cv2.imshow("faces in video", self.img)

class T3(Thread):

    def __init__(self, img):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.img = img

    def run(self):
        cv2.imshow("faces in video", self.img)


def FaceDetection(img):

    imgPreProcessed, imgResized = Faceobj.preprocessing(img)
    faces = Faceobj.detectFace(imgPreProcessed)
    return imgResized, faces

Faceobj = Face()

while (cap.isOpened):

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    # print cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)
    # cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 60)

    if not ret :
        break

    thread_1 = T1(frame)
    thread_1.start()
    thread_1.join()
    thread_2 = T2(thread_1.imgResized, thread_1.faces)
    thread_2.start()
    thread_3 = T3(thread_2.img)
    thread_3.start()
    thread_3.join()

    if (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27):
        break
```

Comment: Have you tried profiling the code to find which part are slowest? I suspect the slow part is when you apply the haar cascade itself (I assume in the file faceDetector.py). You can maybe speed it up by changing the parameters to [`cv2.CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#cascadeclassifier-detectmultiscale)

Comment: Yikes. What's the point of spawning three threads in each iteration? And not just spawning, you start the first one, then join it, start second, then start third using data from second without synchronization and then join the third. So you have no parallelization, with extra overhead and a possible data corruption as a bonus.

Comment: Spend some time learning more about multithreading before you delve into this further -- you seem to be lacking even in the fundamentals, and without that you're bound to fail miserably. That being said, your bottleneck with very likely be in the cascade, which is already optimized quite well -- changing parameters like @HåkenLid suggests seems to be the only option (other than getting more powerful hardware).